# Nan as training loss in a CNN

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a small CNN from scratch to classify images of 10 different animal species. The images have different dimensions, but I'd say around 300x300. Anyway, every image is resized to 224x224 before going into the model.

Here is the network I'm training:

```
    # Convolution 1
    self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()

    # Max pool 1
    self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

    # Convolution 2
    self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
    self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()

    # Max pool 2
    self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

    # Fully connected 1
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 54 * 54, 10)
```

I'm using a SGD optimizer with fixed learning rate = 0.005 and weight decay = 0.01. I'm using a cross entropy function.

The accuracy of the model is good (around 99% after the 43-th epoch). However:

- in some epoch I get a 'nan' as training loss
- in some other epoch the accuracy drops significantly (sometimes the two happen in the same epoch). However, in the next epoch the accuracy comes back to a normal level.

If I understood it correctly a nan in training loss most of the times is caused by gradient values getting too small (underflow) or too big (overflow). Could this be the case?

Should I try by increasing the weight decay to 0.05? Or should I do gradient clipping to avoid exploding gradients? If so which would be a reasonable bound?

Still I don't understand the second issue.

[image: epochs]

[image: epochs]

Comment: What's your loss function?

Comment: it's a cross entropy

Comment: According to the docs https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html the default CrossEntropyLoss with take some kind of weighted average. If all the weights are 0, this would result in a NaN. I'm not sure what exactly the weights are, though.

Comment: Although the learning rate shouldn't be an issue, can you check if a reduced learning rate (something like 0.0005) also produces an NaN value?